# Switching off Alarm during call

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-audiomanager

How does the native call disable the alarm ringing and vibration when a call is ringing and vibrating?

And after the call disconnection the alarm is resuming again in native behaviour.

I tried :

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
```

But of no use. Please help here. I need a similar requirement

Comment: do you initialize your AudioManager properly ?

Comment: yes , the other methods in alarm manager is working.

Comment: can i show the code how you initialize ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7929139

Comment: mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getInstance().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

Comment: audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE); what about this ?

Comment: no, doesn't work either....

Comment: then what about stop the alarm and start ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909040/set-android-alarm-clock-programmatically. hope it helps.

Comment: Since the alarm is set in the native application, we are not having sufficient data to start/stop the application :(

Comment: But what I see is, Alarms are priority interruptions and can never be stopped.... I am able to stop the alarm's ringing tone by using : mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(stream, state); ..... but not the vibration....

Comment: But am pretty not sure how does the alarm vibration stop in native calls , but not third party calling applications.. even in watsapp call or viber call, when the alarm vibration is on, and when it rings, the vibration continuously rings.